# Is it possible to play videos in non-video tags and if so, how do you do it?

Tags: html

We all know that to play a video on a web page in the most basic way you would use something similar to this html code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

However, while snooping around in the inspection feature on a number of different websites and having a look at the tags inside elements, i cant help but notice that some video platforms at times appear to just use a `<div></div>`.

Heres two examples

- youtube:
    If you inspect any video page on Youtube and then right click the video and inspect the html you will see `<video></video>` tag however if you click on the video tag (to initiate the hover state) and the click fullscreen you will see that the video tag seems to disappear and become a div. Here is the link to a youtube video page if you want have a look yourself https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h0MaGc7nx0.
- Twitch:
    If you go on a twitch video page they don't seem to use `<video></video>` tags at all, they use `<div></div>` tags. Initially i thought it was because they do live videos so things work a bit differently but if you have a look at live facebook gaming videos you will notice its the use the conventional `<video></video>` tags. Here is the link to a twitch video page so that you can have a look yourself https://www.twitch.tv/videos/368024918. Here is a link to facebooks gaming page so that you guys can also have a look and compare https://www.facebook.com/gaming/?external_ref=games_video_bookmark.

This sparks my curiosity conciderably. How do they do that? And why would a programmer or company choose this way over the conventional method?

Comment: there is no way to play video without using the video tag, you just need to dig a little bit harder ;)

Comment: What is a video, it's a series of images, and sounds.  Can both of them be done purely in Javascript.   The answer is yes,.   But is it likely video sites do this, No.   There is a fair bit of processing going on when sending video streams.

Comment: @Keith Why not? is it slower, bug prone or just very complicated code required in comparison to a regular video tag? I think if videos were done by programming your own pixels or using a series of images it would be harder for videos to be stolen. Im just thinking about the positives this might bring but drawbacks this might also have. Why shouldnt somebody program their own video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the examples you gave use the `video` tag behind the controls. When you inspect it, you see a div with controls, but if you'll dig deeper (or above) you'll see the `video` hiding.

[image: Live twitch video, with google dev tools open to show the video tag]
[image: Youtube full screen, with google dev tools open to show the video tag]

They make it that way to have more control on the styling of the player and it's controls. Instead of using the default buttons, you can see buttons for pause, play, mute, etc, that onclick uses the video api. That also allows them to pause the video on click anywhere, or to add the cards on the last few seconds on a YouTube video.

There is a way to play a video without the video tag, using old school flash (that's how websites played video before html5) or canvas, by drawing frame after frame (even using canvas, most of the time there is a video tag to get the frames to draw).